# Prevent bulk flow execution from creating duplicates

Tags: visual-workflow, bulkification

I have an `Article__c` custom object.
That article can appear on several `Publication__c` objects, Publications having a `Language__c` field.

When the `Publication__c` record is set *active*, I need to create in a flow a `Translation__c` record for this `Article/Publication.Language`.

Now if I have 2 `Publication__c` records with the same `Language__c` value for the same `Article__c` record, let's say `Publication__c{Name='Mexico'}` and `Publication__c{Name='Spain'}`, I want only one `Translation__c` record for both.

But if they are set *active* in the same transaction, they'll be bulked so the `Translation__c` record won't exist for any of them when the condition is evaluated, and the flow will create two records.

I'd like an idea to prevent this.

It would be easy in an Apex trigger but I need to use only a flow.
I could use a scheduled path with a size of 1 but I need it to be executed sychronously.

Any other idea welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can only be solved in a "flow element" that can handle all records in the transaction.

If a transaction has two records - Mexico and Spain, each record gets its own Flow Interview which is completely unaware of what any other Flow Interview is doing. So the Flow Interview for Spain is unaware of the Flow Interview for Mexico and vice-versa

As you noted, an Apex Trigger (which implicitly can handle up to 200 recs per trigger context) can deal with this.

But for Flow, the solution is to add an Apex Action to the Flow. All the Flow Interviews will pause at the Apex Action and a single call to your invocable Apex method is made passing in a list of `Publication__c`.

Thus, the Apex action is bulkified and can deal with the Spain-Mexico issue, creating only one `Translation__c` because you only need one Spanish translation.

Just remember that if the invocable Apex gets n inputs, it must return n outputs, in the same order as the inputs.

```
@Invocable
public static Translation__c[] translate(Publication__c] pubs) {
  // if pubs[0] were Mexico and pubs[1] were Spain, 
  // then you would create a single Translation__c and 
  // return a list of size 2 containing the same Translation__c in both positions
```

UPDATE

In light of your comment about no Apex, here's an ugly solution:

- Create a scheduled Flow that runs every day - no query on any object
- As the first element, Get all Publication__c that were activated that day.  This will create a collection variable in memory for a single Flow Interview
- Use Flow Loop elements to bucket the Publications into languages (Spanish, Portuguese, German, etc) based on country
- Create Translation records for each language.
- For each created Translation record, loop back through the Publications and update them with the Id of the Translation__c (assuming they need to be connected)

This solution works as long as you are not making lots of newly-activated publications per day and you can wait for the Translations to be created once a day.  Effectively, you are cramming all of the relevant Publications into a single Flow Interview that you can then loop through.

It would also be worth exploring if your org allows, UnofficialSf.com which as Apex actions that can operate on collections in a useful way, making your flow easier to understand. Unofficialsf.com installs as a package.

Comment: Thank you cropredy, it's the same solution as the trigger but I'm not allowed to do Apex, hence my question. There might be no solution, beside moving the logic to the parent object (update a tech field after update and query the children before inserting the Translation) but I hate to update to objects when only one needs to be.

Comment: I offer a new solution given your constraints

Comment: Thanks again, but this solution is far from synchronous. I finally did it with a flag field on the parent object and queries on all children and loops. It's ugly too but it works. The unofficialSf solution looks good though, but I couldn't install it, a dependency problem...